# What is the syntax for adding jQuery to the SharePoint 2010 Master page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, jquery

I am unable to load jquery to SharePoint 2010 masterpage.
I have tried below syntax

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" 
name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" runat="server"  />
```

Following errors are displaying

> Bootstrap's javascript requires jquery
>
> Expected identifier - jquery.3.2.1.js

Bootstrap and java script are working properly.
Could you please tell me the syntax for adding jquery to SharePoint 2010 masterpage?

Answer (score 3):

This helped me in the past.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" runat="server" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="True" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It would work

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 or
<script src="../../SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```